# Powerpivot Slicers Multiple Columns

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I have a Power Pivot dataset with multiple date fields (which I have converted into Year and Month only yyyymm). I have created a slicer for each of the date fields which are used in a CubeValue formula:

```
 =CUBEVALUE("PowerPivot Data","[Measures].[CountofOrganisationID]",Slicer_ApprovalDateMonthNumber)
```

I would like users to be able to select one Date slicer which can be used in multiple CubeValue Member Expressions AND where there are multiple values selected in the slicer.

1. I can get this to work using multiple slicers (each on one column in the dataset).
2. I can get this to work with one slicer used by all columns for one selected value.

But I cannot get both 1. and 2. above to function together, with one slicer only.

**UPDATE:**
So sample PowerPivot table (columns) is:
**Organisation | ReceivedDate | ApprovedDate | State | etc...**

If I use a slicer I can only pick one Column per slicer, rather than using one slicer (named "Date") which can filter by Received Date AND Approved Date in different cells/places.

So the user currently has to select the same date value for Received and Approved in 2 separate slicers which affects multiple cells (using different queries)

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following with the multiple slicers and multiple values thing. Can you post an example?

Comment: Does the update suffice or would you like a visual?

Comment: I think I understand your data now. If the received and approved data re almost always the same (when the user selects it), then why not have a role playing date dimension and create calculations that use the appropriate date field so that you just choose date and they all update?

Comment: Yes Exactly! Because I have also just used the Year and Month (in a new column "yyyymm") as the date selection, so this should be selectable in one slicer for both date columns.